# Difference between DESCRIBE and CONSTRUCT in sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, ontology, triplestore

I am new in sparql. I am reading these slides

1. [image]
2. [image]

Similarities :

1. Both of them result in RDF graph
2. Both of them results in RDF/XML or Turtle

What is the difference between them ? Please Explain .

Comment: `DESCRIBE` is not really specified how to evaluate by a triple store. It's main purpose is to "describe" entities, what this means is up to the triple store, but the result has to be a set of RDF triples.. You can do something like `DESCRIBE <SOME_ENTITY_URI>` and it will return some RDF triples that somehow describe the entity, i.e. ideally return related triples in the RDF graph. Common implementations do return a) all outgoing triples b) as well as incoming triples c) and sometimes also do resolve blank nodes, i.e. append triples that describe blank nodes directly related to the entity.

Comment: what about the "CONSTRUCT" keyword?

Comment: @aaaaa with `CONSTRUCT` you generate/RDF triples out of the solutions from the `WHERE` clause by using a template you specify in it - as it is done in the example you posted - the query generate RDF `?author :hasWritten ?work` statements with the bindings for `?author` and `?work` produced by matches in the body of the query

Comment: @aaaaa compared to `DESCRIBE`, that is completely specified by the SPARQL specs, as Damyan said, it generates those triples specified in the template for bindings matching the query pattern.

Comment: It appears that you may not have looked at [the actual SPARQL specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) yet... So I'll suggest that you do that. Note that the `DESCRIBE` section is "informative", which means that implementations are generally free to deliver what they like, while the `CONSTRUCT` section is "normative", which means that implementations are required to deliver what's described there.

Comment: Also, without a link to the slidedeck, it's hard to know for sure -- but I think those slides are rather old, and based on SPARQL 1.0 (if not earlier). Results of both `DESCRIBE` and `CONSTRUCT` queries may now be in many serializations -- not only RDF/XML or Turtle.